# I need to query a single table multiple times and show the results in a single result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, pivot

I have a need to query a single table multiple times and show the results in a single result set. Below is example of the table.

```
Period | Employer    | Hours
SEP20  | Emp1        | 5
SEP20  | Emp1        | 10
OCT20  | Emp2        | 10
SEP20  | Emp2        | 10
SEP20  | Emp3        | 10
```

I want to sum the hours and show the result as below, I also need a column that sums hours for all Employers with the exception Emp1.

```
Period| Emp1      | Emp2     | Emp3    | Allexcept Emp1
SEP20 | 15        | 10       | 10      | 20
OCT20 | 10        | NULL     | NULL    |  NULL
```

I am looking for the most efficient query. Many thanks

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixes list of employees, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select period,
    sum(case when employer =  'Emp1' then hours end) emp1,
    sum(case when employer =  'Emp2' then hours end) emp2,
    sum(case when employer =  'Emp3' then hours end) emp3,
    sum(case when employer <> 'Emp1' then hours end) all_but_emp1
from mytable
group by period
```